# how to use css inheritance for button colors

Tags: css

I've got a basic button style created. I want a blue version, and a gray version. the blue class selector and the gray class selector are never recognized, why not??

```
a.checkout-button {
    -webkit-transition:border-color 0.218s;
    background-position: initial initial;
    background-repeat: initial initial;
    border:0 solid #DCDCDC;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Arimo', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.checkout-button .blue {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 10%,0% 70%,from(#4533A9),to(#202020));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 10%,0% 70%,from(#4533A9),to(#202020));
}
a.checkout-button .gray {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 10%,0% 70%,from(#4533A9),to(#202020));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 10%,0% 70%,from(#4533A9),to(#202020));
}
```

and the html

```
<a class="checkout-button gray" id="cancel-btn" href="">Cancel</a>
<a class="checkout-button blue" id="express-checkout-btn" href="">Express Checkout</a>
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Hi Daven, welcome to SO! As an addition to the code snippets in your question, I suggest using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show your code in action. jsfiddle can help identify problems and make answering the question a lot easier.

Comment: Example with Rob d'Apice's solution http://jsfiddle.net/BZRL6/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line:

```
a.checkout-button .gray {
```

to this:

```
a.checkout-button.gray {
```

**And** change this line:

```
.a.checkout-button .blue {
```

To this:

```
a.checkout-button.blue {
```

Edit: the reason for this is that the correct css format is to string classes together with a `.` in between. If you leave a space, like this: `a.checkout-button .gray`, this will apply the style to any element that has the class `gray` INSIDE the `a.checkout-button` element.

Comment: thanks, for both the solution and the distinction between the space and no space. working perfectly now.